# How to decimate / decrease number of tic labels in gnuplot matrix

Tags: matrix, text, gnuplot, axis-labels

I have a matrix of data, which is an output of automatic music transcription program. I want to plot it using gnuplot, assigning appropriate labels. [Here's my dropbox with some data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/akhist723ssi9sw/AAAvSRCk2J8wJnlUtmyhNjxca?dl=0), where Intensity.dat is actual data, example.stn is a column of string values, **some of which** are to be displayed on y axis and example.all is just a result of `paste example.stn Intensity.dat > example.all` Script:

```
reset
set title "Intensity detection"
set palette negative grayscale
set cbrange [0.01:1]
set xlabel "Time [s]"
set ylabel "Musical note"
set terminal qt font "Verdana,16"
set logscale cb
xincr=0.04644
yincr=1
plot 'example.all' u (($1+0.5)*xincr):($2*yincr):3 matrix with image
```

produces
[plot produced by script 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufFC7.jpg). Everything's OK, now just tic labels...

After I change the last line to `plot 'example.all' u (($1+0.5)*xincr):($2*yincr):3 matrix rowheaders with image`, the y-axis becomes too densly populated (**It's plot2.jpg from my dropbox, link on top**. Sorry guys, I'm new and it doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links).
What I want is a way to present only the labels I want (or hide others, whatever), not all at a time (because it looks unreadable). I'd also like to be able to quickly change them to the others when I need to do so. Supposingly, I want to display every 12th label, but still keep entire matrix with all rows plotted. Or every 12th starting from 2nd label AND every 12th starting from 6th. I've already tried many ways but I'm stuck. Functions like :ytics() or :yticlabels() can't make it, at least for me. And yes, I need this Verdana 16, and removing labels completely is out of question.

I'll be extra grateful if the method applies also for x-axis, as I have an analogical problem with x-axis in other plot, but I generally appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate plotting the image from plotting the ytics like this:

```
condition(n) = (ceil(n)%12-2 == 0) || (ceil(n)%12-6 == 0)

plot 'Intensity.dat' u (($1+0.5)*xincr):($2*yincr):3 matrix with image ,\
     'example.stn' u (NaN):0:ytic(condition($0) ? strcol(1) : "")  notitle
```

The function `condition` checks whether the label should be plotted or not. I have used `ceil` to convert from a real number to an integer which is required by the modulo operator (%). The `condition` function is called with the linenumber `$0`. The `NaN` while plotting 'example.stn' avoids plotting data points while keeping the chance for setting the labels. If the condition is met (12th label starting from 2nd or 12th starting from 6th), we use the actual label, else an empty string is used.

[image: note intensities]

Comment: First of all, thank you for fast reply, I belive it's the solution. For anyone who looks for x-axis labelling, it's
    `condition(n) = (ceil(n)%12-2 == 0) || (ceil(n)%12-6 == 0)`
and plotting part
    `plot 'example.dat' u (($1)*xincr):($2*yincr):3 matrix with image ,\
     'example.stn' u 0:(NaN):xtic(condition($0) ? strcol(1) : "")  notitle`